# Stanford pos tagger not displaying the output elements in Python (MAC)

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

```
#-*- coding:Utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import os
java_path = "/usr/libexec/java_home" # replace this
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger

french_postagger = POSTagger("stanford-postagger-full-2014-10-26/models/french.tagger", "stanford-postagger-full-2014-10-26/stanford-postagger.jar", encoding="utf-8")
english_postagger = POSTagger("stanford-postagger-full-2014-10-26/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger", "stanford-postagger-full-2014-10-26/stanford-postagger.jar", encoding="utf-8")


print french_postagger.tag("siddhartha is a good boy".split())
```

the result is as follows:

```
[('', u'/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home')]
```

instead I need to see the words and their tags.

Comment: so whats the problem exactly ?

Comment: @Kasra the result is a list with a blank character and a system path while I need to get the actual results, is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: all things seems correct are you sure about the path of `stanford-postagger.jar` or can you try without `encoding` ? is your code in same directory with `stanford-postagger-full-2014-10-26`?

Comment: @Kasra yes, I copied the stanford pos unzipped folder inside my project folder. If the path were wrong it would give an error ?

Comment: tried without encoding too, same stupid list as result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part of your code:

```
java_path = "/usr/libexec/java_home" # replace this
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```

Where did that code from? It looks like you should replace it. If your setup is like mine, changing that first line to `java_path = "/usr/bin/java"` fixes the problem. Actually, if your setup is like mine, just **deleting those two lines completely** fixes the problem (while including them reproduces it):

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
french_postagger = POSTagger("models/french.tagger", "stanford-postagger.jar", encoding="utf-8")
english_postagger = POSTagger("models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger", "stanford-postagger.jar", encoding="utf-8")

print french_postagger.tag("siddhartha is a good boy".split())
> [[(u'siddhartha', u'ADV'), (u'is', u'VPP'), (u'a', u'V'), (u'good', u'ET'), (u'boy', u'ET')]]
```